# invalid_grant trying to get OpenID Connect token from PayPal

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, paypal, authentication

I am following the [Guide: Integrate Log In with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/) in attempt to make it work on WordPress 4.7.1. I have successfully embed the Log In with PayPal button. Clicking on it bring the login, which then redirects to "returnurl".

I'm currently stuck trying to pass the authorization code received in the previous step to the tokenservice endpoint to receive an access token.

My "returnurl" has this curl code (as suggested by [Guide: grant token from authorization code](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/#tokenservice_createFromAuthorizationCode)):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init( 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice' ); 
// not $curl = curl_init( 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$code = $_GET['code'];  // The code from the previous request
$redirect_uri = 'http://xxxxxx.contemplate.me.ke/';

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $code
) );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,
    "My-Client-Id" . ":" . 
    "My-Secret");

$auth = curl_exec( $curl ); 
print '$auth = ';print_r($auth); // to see the error
$secret = json_decode($auth); 
$access_key = $secret->access_token;
?>
```

All I get from this after logging in is:

```
$auth = {"error_description":"Grant type is null","error":"invalid_grant","correlation_id":"0f5787fc6413f","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just found [How to Implement User Log-in with PayPal](https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-user-log-paypal/#the-resultphp-file) which uses GET instead of POST and it worked! I got my token.